# Há como implementar uma interface em uma classe de uma DLL que só consigo ler?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, interface, dll, tdd

Estou utilizando uma DLL que possui diversas classes. Gostaria de implementar dinamicamente interfaces para essas classes, para que eu consiga realizar testes unitários fazendo um *mock* das mesmas.

Há alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Exemplo:

A DLL tem uma classe `Comunicador`

```
public class Comunicador
{
    public void Executar()
    {
        //executa
    }
}
```

Há algum jeito de eu fazer com que essa classe implemente a interface abaixo dinamicamente?

```
public interface IComunicador
{
    void Executar();
}
```

Dessa maneira, eu quero que uma propriedade

```
public IComunicador Comunicador { get; set; }
```

Consiga entender o seguinte:

```
Comunicador = new Comunicador();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E se você criasse uma classe `MeuComunicador` só para implementar a interface, resolveria seu problema?

Exemplo:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MinhaClasse obj = new MinhaClasse();

        obj.ObjComunicador = new MeuComunicador();
        obj.ObjComunicador.Executar();
        Console.WriteLine("Fim");
    }
}


public class MinhaClasse
{
    public IComunicador ObjComunicador   {get;set;}
}


public class Comunicador //Essa classe você não pode mexer né ?!
{
    public void Executar()
    {
        //supondo que o metodo do comunicador original faça algo...
        Console.WriteLine("Executando método do comunicador ... ");
    }
}

public class MeuComunicador : Comunicador, IComunicador
{

}

public interface IComunicador
{
    void Executar();
}
```

Resultado:

> Executando método do comunicador ...
>
> Fim

Testei no .NetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9AwVEA

Comment: Acho que como já há bastante código legado implementado essa seja a solução mais viável por enquanto. Adicionar um padrão de projeto como mencionado pelo @Maniero seria complicado neste ponto. Vou testar e dou um retorno.

Comment: Obrigado! Essa solução resolve o meu problema.

Answer (score 4):

Até o C# 7 não é possível. Mesmo quando puder haverá restrições, ainda não totalmente definidas, do que pode fazer.

Para testar tem como acessar o método se você sabe que ele está implementado, não é o ideal, mas é possível forçar o teste.

Não só para o teste, mas para o uso em produção é possível criar um padrão de projeto que ajude lidar com isto, embora também não seja o ideal, mas pode ser a única forma. Provavelmente um [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). No caso pelo descrito na pergunta nem precisaria implementar nada, apenas ter um outro objeto que tem a interface e que delegue para o que já existe.

Note que você só consegue acessar o que é público neste adaptador. Nunca dá para acessar algo privado, a não ser por reflexão, o que seria uma enorme gambiarra criando riscos de manutenção.

Não sei se é a melhor alternativa para a questão, mas é uma delas. Existem [outros padrões que podem ajudar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_pattern).

Provavelmente a solução dada pelo Rovann Linhalis é mais adequada.

Considero isso gambiarra, mas em código legado gambiarras são necessárias.

Achei curioso se falar em TDD de algo que já existe.

Comment: Não seria o caso de usar [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: É legado sim, mas como estou implementando código novo por TDD acabei citando erroneamente.

O problema de chamar essa classe que está pública é que ela tem chamada de banco de dados, o que eu não posso fazer no meu teste unitário. Vou dar uma olhada no Adapter para ver se ele atende, obrigado! (E sim, não chegaria ao ponto de usar reflection só para conseguir criar um teste desse tipo)

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática Acho que não. MEF é para outra coisa.